# Toroidal Split Complete Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, extremal-combinatorics

The paper [On the Planar Split Thickness of Graphs](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04839) shows how non-planar graphs can be split to make planar graphs.  For example, they offer a [split $K_{6,10}$](http://11011110.livejournal.com/321850.html).

[image]

I would instead like to make split [toroidal graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroidal_graph). The [Shrikhande graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrikhande_graph) (below), $K_7$, and the [Möbius–Kantor graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius%E2%80%93Kantor_graph) are some toroidal graphs.

[image]

It seems that $K_{13}$ (2), $K_{19}$ (3), $K_{25}$ (4), $K_{31}$ (5), $K_{37}$ (6), $K_{43}$ (7), and $K_{49}$ (8) could all be realized as split toroidal graphs. In particular, can a $10 \times 10 $ grid with 1-25 each occurring 4 times be made so that all orthogonal or right diagonal pairings are distinct?

Here is a non-solution for $K_{25}$ as a toroidal 4-split with \ diagonals.  Only 282 of the 300 edges are present. Above the grid are graphs made from doubled edges and missing edges.

[image: not k25]